# Не подключаются стили, которые работают в IDE

Tags: файлы, css, index

Проблема в том, что если открывать файл index.html браузером, не важно каким, не подключаются стили и js-файлы. При этом, работаю в Brackets, если использовать Live Preview, то все отображается идеально

Comment: Попробуйте ознакомится с терминами относительных и абсолютных путей к файлам. К символам / и ../ в начале URL.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь Я знаком с этими терминами. Если бы в путях были ошибки, то файлы не подключились бы и в Brackets

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь браузер не хотел видеть папку, почему-то... создал новую просто, перекопировал файлы и все заработало